# For Each SQL Insert change the box ID +1

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

In this situation I am generating a dynamic text box based on a list box click to capture a data point, once done I need to do a for each select and insert them individually to the database. My issue follows.

We have the

```
For Each item in my listbox
--Call SQL connection--
where @Var = Textbox1.text.tostring()
```

upon the next run (next for each item) I need the code to increase `Textbox1` to `textbox2`.

Any general thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Why converting `Textbox1.Text` to String?

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
        int iterator = 1; 
        foreach (ListboxItem item in YourListBox.Items)
        {
            TextBox tbx = new TextBox();
            tbx.ID = "Textbox" + iterator.ToString();
            //your SQL operation 
            iterator++; 
        }
```